# error converting data type varchar to int - Excel VBA SQL

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I am trying to pull zipcodes from a Microsoft SQL Database and everything works good with US Zipcodes, but once I start to use Canadian Zip Codes, I get the following message:

conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'L0S1J0' to data type int.

I know that L0S1J0 is not a integer, but what I don't understand is why Excel VBA wants to pull the data as an integer. I tried to search for pulling data in ways other than int, but I am not having any luck with the right keywords. I have tried things like Cast and Convert, but I cant get anything to work, other than removing the Canadian Zip Codes out of the database.

Here is my query that I am currently running and the Zip Codes are stored under the LookupID field.

```
Select Distance1, Distance2, LookupID FROM excel.dbo.miles WHERE LookupID =" & Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2").Value
```

Any help in this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the rest of your VBA look like?

Comment: This still gave me the error message. Thanks for your assistance however :-)

Comment: I had noticed the missing quote marks but I expected you to see a different error though. Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Just for reference when I try a similar query I get: Invalid column name 'L0S1J0'. Who knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in your where clause.  Change to:

```
WHERE LookupID ='" & Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C2").Value & "'"
```

You need to put single quotes around string literals.

You should consider doing a parameterized query to protect from SQL Injection issues.  For example with ADO use the CreateParameter method.

Comment: Pefect! Thank you for your time. Works like a charm now :-D